# Simple way to parameterize two perpendicular vectors

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

Given are two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\bar{u}$ and $\bar{v}$, such that they are perpendicular ($\bar{u}\cdot\bar{v}=0$) and of equal length ($|\bar{u}|=|\bar{v}|$).

**Is there a "nice" way to parameterize these vectors**?

Obviously, there should be only 4 parameters involved, but if one tries to just express $v_z$ and $u_z$ in terms of $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$, a rather ugly expression is arrived at. It seems a geometrically inspired parameterization where one of the parameters is the vector length should do the trick, but I can't seem to think of one that doesn't involve even more complicated expressions such as those arrived at using spherical coordinates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple parametrization, because this is not such a simple object. The set of ordered pairs of orthogonal   unit vectors  is naturally identified with the unit tangle  bundle of $S^2$: $u$ determines a point on the sphere, and $v$ is a tangent vector at that point.  This bundle  can be identified with $SO(3)$ or $\mathbb RP^3$: see the answers at [The circle bundle of $S^2$ and real projective space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60522/). I think that using unit quaternions (as Stephen Montgomery-Smith suggested) is about as simple parametrization as you could get.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this isn't quite what you want, but this looks like it should just be $\mathbb{R}^{> 0} \times S^2 \times S^1$, if you don't allow the zero vector anyways.

Namely, you fix a radius $r> 0$, then a point on the sphere of radius $r$ about the origin $S^2$, and then pick a point perpendicular to it, which lies on $S^2 \cap$ the perpendicular hyperplane, a.k.a. $S^1$.

Comment: The parameterization of that plane is not trivial unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?  Any rotation can be represented by a unit quaternion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

So take any quaternion, calculate its norm $s$, divide the quaternion by $s$, code it into a rotation $R$, and then take $u$ and $v$ to be the first two columns of $R$ multiplied by $s$.

The processes of coding a rotation by a quaternion is quite subtle, but it is very clever.  And I believe the graphics card industry use it.

Comment: You still end up with a really complex parameterization. I was hoping it could be a bit simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

Despite multiple answers that claim that there is no nice way, there is:

The first vector can be parametrised in [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) (be careful about the different conventions of physicists and mathematicians; physics used here)
$$
    \vec{u} = r\begin{pmatrix}
        \sin\theta\cos\varphi \\
        \sin\theta\sin\varphi \\
        \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix} \qquad r\in\mathbb{R}_0^+, \ \theta\in[0,\pi], \ \varphi\in[0,2\pi[
$$

Now we want $\vec{v}$ to be orthogonal to $\vec{u}$, but be able point in every direction that fulfils this restriction: we need the orthogonal complement of $\{\vec{u}\}$.
The spherical coordinate system has a [natural, local, orthonormal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates) $\{\vec{e}_r, \vec{e}_\theta, \vec{e}_\varphi\}$ of vectors, that point in the direction the position would change by increasing $r, \theta, \varphi$ respectively. You can get them by differentiating your position by these variables and then normalising the results:
$$
    \vec{e}_r = \begin{pmatrix}
        \sin\theta\cos\varphi \\
        \sin\theta\sin\varphi \\
        \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix} \qquad \vec{e}_\theta = \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos\theta\cos\varphi \\
        \cos\theta\sin\varphi \\
        -\sin\theta
    \end{pmatrix} \qquad \vec{e}_\varphi = \begin{pmatrix}
        -\sin\theta\sin\varphi \\
        \sin\theta\cos\varphi \\
        0
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
$\vec{e}_r$ points in the direction of $\vec{u}$, therefore span of the other two basis vectors is our orthogonal complement:
$$
    \{\vec{u}\}^\perp = \text{span}\{\vec{e}_\theta, \vec{e}_\varphi\}
$$
We use [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) to describe $\vec{v}$ in this subspace, with the same length $r$ of $\vec{u}$ as requested:
$$
    \vec{v} = r(\cos\alpha\vec{e}_\theta+\sin\alpha\vec{e}_\varphi)
$$

Concluded:
$$
    \vec{u} = r\begin{pmatrix}
        \sin\theta\cos\varphi \\
        \sin\theta\sin\varphi \\
        \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix} \qquad \vec{v} = r\left(\cos\alpha\begin{pmatrix}
        \cos\theta\cos\varphi \\
        \cos\theta\sin\varphi \\
        -\sin\theta
    \end{pmatrix} + \sin\alpha\begin{pmatrix}
        -\sin\theta\sin\varphi \\
        +\sin\theta\cos\varphi \\
        0
    \end{pmatrix}\right) \\
    r\in\mathbb{R}_0^+, \ \theta\in[0,\pi], \ \varphi\in[0,2\pi[, \ \alpha\in[0,2\pi[
$$

This answer can be generalised into $N$ dimensions using [hyper spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) with $2N-2$ parameters:
$$
    \begin{aligned}
    \vec{u} &= r\begin{pmatrix}
        \cos\theta_1 \\
        \sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2 \\
        \sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_3 \\
        \vdots \\
        \sin\theta_1\cdots\sin\theta_{N-2}\cos\theta_{N-1} \\
        \sin\theta_1\cdots\sin\theta_{N-2}\sin\theta_{N-1}
    \end{pmatrix} \\
    \vec{v} &= r(\cos\varphi_1\vec{e}_{\theta_1} \\
    &\qquad+ \sin\varphi_1\cos\varphi_2\vec{e}_{\theta_2} \\
    &\qquad+ \sin\varphi_1\sin\varphi_2\cos\varphi_3\vec{e}_{\theta_3} \\
    &\qquad+ \cdots \\
    &\qquad+ \sin\varphi_1\cdots\sin\varphi_{N-3}\cos\varphi_{N-2}\vec{e}_{\theta_{N-2}} \\
    &\qquad+ \sin\varphi_1\cdots\sin\varphi_{N-3}\sin\varphi_{N-2}\vec{e}_{\theta_{N-1}})
    \end{aligned} \\
r\in\mathbb{R}_0^+, \ \theta_1, \dots, \theta_{N-2}, \varphi_1, \dots, \varphi_{N-3}\in[0,\pi], \ \theta_{N-1}, \varphi_{N-2}\in[0,2\pi[
$$