# Computing homology/cohomology of unit tangent bundle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

This is a continuation of my previous question here: [Homeomorphism for computing homology/cohomology of unit tangent bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2146606/homeomorphism-for-computing-homology-cohomology-of-unit-tangent-bundle)
I am trying to calculate the homology and cohomology of the space
$$T=\{(v,w)\in S^n \times S^n \mid v \cdot w = 0 \}$$
which is the unit tangent bundle, or sometimes called the Stiefel 2-manifold $V_2(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$. Instead of using a Gysin sequence ([The circle bundle of $S^2$ and real projective space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60522/the-circle-bundle-of-s2-and-real-projective-space)) or determining the cell structure of $T$ based on the cell structure of $SO(n)$ (see previous question), the goal is to define
$$T_+=\{(v,w) \in T \mid v_0 \ge 0,  \ \  T_-=\{(v,w) \in T \mid v_0 \le 0 \}$$
where $v_0$ is the first coordinate of $v$ in $(v,w)$. Then I am supposed to prove that
$$T_+ \cong S_+ \times S^{n−1}, \ \ T_- \cong S_- \times S^{n-1}$$
where $S_+=\{v\in S^n \mid v_0 \ge 0\}$ and $S_-=\{v\in S^n \mid v_0 \le 0\}$. This proof is done in the previous question.

This might be obvious, but from here I don't see how having these homeomorphisms gives us an alternate technique for homology/cohomology calculations.

**Update (3/17/17):** My first thought was obviously to use Mayer-Vietoris. 
\begin{eqnarray*}
H_{n+1}(T) &\rightarrow& H_n(T_+ \cap T_-) \rightarrow H_n(T_+) \oplus H_n(T_-) \rightarrow H_n(T) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(T_+ \cap T_-) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(T_+) \oplus H_{n-1}(T_-) \\
\cdots &\rightarrow& H_1(T_+) \oplus H_1(T_-) \rightarrow H_1(T) \rightarrow H_0(T_+ \cap T_-) \rightarrow H_0(T_+) \oplus H_0(T_-) \rightarrow H_0(T) \rightarrow 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $T_+ \cap T_- \simeq S^{n-1}$ and $T_{\pm} \simeq S_{\pm} \times S^{n-1}$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
H_{n+1}(T) &\overset{\partial_*}\rightarrow& H_n(S^{n-1}) \overset{\iota_*}\rightarrow H_n(S_+ \times S^{n-1}) \oplus H_n(S_- \times S^{n-1}) \overset{1-f_*}\rightarrow H_n(T) \overset{\partial_*}\rightarrow H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) \\ 
&\overset{\iota_*}\rightarrow& H_{n-1}(S_+ \times S^{n-1}) \oplus H_{n-1}(S_- \times S^{n-1}) \cdots \overset{\iota_*}\rightarrow H_1(S_+ \times S^{n-1}) \oplus H_1(S_- \times S^{n-1}) \\
&\overset{1-f_*}\rightarrow& H_1(T) \overset{\partial_*}\rightarrow H_0(S^{n-1}) \overset{\iota_*}\rightarrow H_0(S_+ \times S^{n-1}) \oplus H_0(S_- \times S^{n-1}) \overset{1-f_*}\rightarrow H_0(T) \rightarrow 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
So take for example $n = 4$. Then $H_i(S^{n-1}) = H_i(S^3)$ which is only nontrivial for $i = 0, 3$. Also $H_i(S_+ \times S^{n-1}) \simeq H_i(S_+) \times H_i(S^{n-1}) = H_i(S^{n-1}) = H_i(S^3)$ since $S_+$ is contractible. So 
\begin{eqnarray*}
0 &\rightarrow & H_{4}(T) \overset{\partial_*}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \overset{\iota_*}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \overset{1-f_*}\rightarrow H_3(T) \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0 \oplus 0 \rightarrow H_2(T) \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow H_1(T) \overset{\partial_*}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \\
&\overset{\iota_*}\hookrightarrow& \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}
\overset{1-f_*}\rightarrow H_0(T) \rightarrow 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
From here, $H_2(T) = 0$. Since $\iota_*$ is injective, by exactness we get $\partial_*: H_1(T) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is the zero map. Thus, $H_1(T) = 0$, **but that is not correct**. (I think $H_1(T)$ is supposed to be $\mathbb{Z}_2$.) **Also, how do we determine $f_*$? Should $f_*$ sometimes be multiplication by 2 and sometimes be 0 depending on whether $n$ is even or odd?** Is the following passage from Hatcher's VB text relevant to the explanation? (And if so, could someone further explain it? I don't really understand what it's saying).
[image]

Comment: Presumably you should use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Comment: @JimBelk Of course. The question is updated with my attempt at that.

Comment: Your "naive" equality "$T\cong (S_+\times S^{n−1}) \cup (S_- \times S^{n-1}) = (S_+ \cup S_-) \times S^{n-1} =S^n×S^{n−1}$" is completely wrong. While two two pieces $T_+$ and $T_-$ are indeed homeomorphic to what you say they are homeomorphic to, they are not subsets of $S^n\times S^n$ and that last equality you wrote makes no sense!

Comment: That's like saying that since the upper half of $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ and the lower half to $[-1,0]$ then $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $[-1,1]$...

Comment: On the other hand the intersection $T_+\cap T_-$ is the subset of your $T$ of points $(u,v)$ with the first component of $u$ equal to zero. Are you sure that is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$?

Comment: When $n=4$, you get $T^1 S^4$ which  is actually $2$-connected, so the conclusion of your MV calculation above is fine.  In general, $T^1 S^n$ is $(n-2)$-connected.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez right, that makes sense. Then what is $T_+ \cap T_-$? When I draw out pictures (for $n =3$ for example) then $(v,w)$ for $v_0 =0$ looks like two great circles on the sphere that are perpendicular. So is $T_+ \cap T_-$ the same as $S^2 \times S^2$ (or $S^{n-1} \times S^{n-1}$) in general? I worry because (in the $n = 3$ case) the two great circles seem to intersect at two points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do believe that Mayer-Vietoris is the way to go here. But a few things need clarification:

First, $T_+\cap T_-$ is not $S^{n-1}$ but $S^{n-1}\times S^{n-1}$ (the first factor is the equator of $S^n$). If you think in terms of cellular decomposition then the homology of that is given by

$$H_k(T_+\cap T_-)\simeq \left\lbrace \array{\mathbb{Z}\hfill &\text{if $k=0$ }\hfill \\\mathbb{Z^2}\hfill &\text{if $k=n-1$}\\\mathbb{Z}\hfill &\text{if $k=2n-2$}\hfill }\right.$$

Now $T_+$ and $T_-$ both deformation retract on $S^{n-1}$ since $S_\pm$ are contractible. Therefore:

$$H_k(T_\pm)\simeq \left\lbrace \array{\mathbb{Z}\hfill &\text{if $k=0$ }\hfill \\\mathbb{Z}\hfill &\text{if $k=n-1$}\hfill }\right.$$

---

So the interesting places in your exact sequence are around $k=2n-2$, $k=n-1$ and $k=0$. **The case $n=2$ contains overlaps and has to be treated separately. We first assume that $n>2$.**

Around $k=2n-2$ you have
$$0\to H_{2n-1}(T)\to \mathbb{Z}\to0$$
whereby $$\color{red} {H_{2n-1}(T)\simeq \mathbb{Z}}$$

Around $k=n-1$ you get (remember $n>2$) $$0\to H_n(T)\to \mathbb{Z}^2\to \mathbb{Z}^2\to H_{n-1}(T)\to 0$$

We have to understand what the middle map $\mathbb{Z}^2\to \mathbb{Z}^2$ does. It is easy to see that it is the map $$(a,b)\mapsto (0,b)$$ Indeed, the first generator is the equator of $S^n$ and bounds a disc in both $T_+$ and $T_-$, whereas nothing happens to the second generator.

Therefore $$\color{red} {H_n(T)\simeq \mathbb{Z}}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\color{red} {H_{n-1}(T)\simeq \mathbb{Z}}$$

Finally, near $k=0$ you get $$0\to H_1(T)\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}^2\to H_{0}(T)\to 0$$ and the middle map is clearly injective, so that $H_1(T)=0$  $\ $ (and obviously $H_0(T)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$).

---

**Now if $n=2$.** You still get

$$0\to H_3(T)\to \mathbb{Z}\to 0$$
whereby $$\color{red} {H_3(T)\simeq \mathbb{Z}}$$

But now the dimensions $1$ and $2$ overlap in $$0\to H_2(T)\to \mathbb{Z}^2\to \mathbb{Z}^2\to H_{1}(T)\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}^2\to H_0(T)\to 0$$
where again the map $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}^2$ is injective, which gives 
$$0\to H_2(T)\to \mathbb{Z}^2\to \mathbb{Z}^2\to H_{1}(T)\to 0$$

From here an analysis of what the maps do is required, and I don't think that you can avoid the kind of arguments given in the other questions that you mentioned.