# Is the Hairy Ball Theorem equivalent to saying that the Hopf Fibration has no global sections?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fiber-bundles, hopf-fibration

The [Hairy Ball Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) states that $S^2$ has no nonvanishing tangent vector fields. But if we did have such a field then we could normalise each vector so that it lay on the unit circle of the tangent plane at that point. These unit circles form a bundle over $S^2$ with fibre $S^1$. The Hairy Ball Theorem is therefore equivalent to saying that this bundle has no global section.

Since this is a nontrivial $S^2$-bundle with fibre $S^1$ I thought that it might be the Hopf Fibration. Is it? If not, what is the total space?

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60522/the-circle-bundle-of-s2-and-real-projective-space.

Comment: @RobArthan So the Hopf Fibration is a double cover of this bundle?

Comment: Yes. The double covering of the total spaces is the [plate trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_trick).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total space is $SO(3) \cong \mathbb{RP}^3$. You can see this because $SO(3)$ acts freely and transitively on it, by first rotating points in $S^2$ and then by rotating tangent vectors at a given point.

It's an interesting exercise to similarly identify the total spaces of the unit tangent bundles of the other closed surfaces (fixing, say, a metric of constant curvature).