# Cohomology computation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, hodge-theory

Let $\Sigma_2$ be the second Hirzebruch surface and $f : \Sigma_2 \to X$ that contracts the exceptional section $E$. Since $E^2=-2$, $X$ has a quadratic singularity at $p := f(E)$.

If $U'$ is a small ball around $p$, $U = U' \cap X$ and $V = X \backslash \{p\}$, then $X = U \cup V$, $V$ is a line bundle over $\Bbb P^1$ and $U \cap V$ is a $\Bbb C^*$-bundle over $\mathbb P^1$. They are both classified by a number $a \in \mathbb Z$.

> **Question 1** :  What is $a$ ? (My guess is $a = \pm 2$).

Since $U$ is contractible we get a long exact sequence $$ 0 \to H^1(X) \to H^1(V) = 0 \to H^1(U \cap V) \to  H^2(X) \to H^2(V) \to H^2(U \cap V) \to H^3(X) \to H^3(V) = 0 \to H^3(U \cap V) \to H^4(X) \to 0$$

Hence we get $H^4(X) = \Bbb C, H^1(X) = 0$, and an exact sequence $$ 0 \to H^2(X) \to \Bbb C \to H^2(U \cap V) \to H^3(X) \to 0 $$

> **Question 2** : How to compute $H^2(X)$ and $H^3(X)$ ?

I suspect $H^2(X) = \Bbb C$ and $H^3(X) = 0$.

Moreover I would like to understand :

> **Question 3** : How to compute the mixed Hodge structure on $X$ associated to the resolution ?

It's clear for $H^0$ and $H^4$. I don't really know what happens for $H^2(X)$. In fact, I read that in such setting, the Hodge structure is never pure, which is really what motivated my question.

Comment: Perhaps the following fact is useful to you: $\Sigma_d$ can be obtained by the following way: Take rational normal curve of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^d$, cone it in $\mathbb A^{d+1}$, and blowup the cone point.

Comment: @AGlearner : Thanks, you probably need to take the cone in $\Bbb P^d$ since you want it to be compact. In fact I already used what you wrote to describe $U \cap V$ and $V$. If you know how to answer any of my questions I would be pretty happy !

Comment: This doesn't help with everything you ask, but as I recall the topological classification of Hirzebruch surfaces is quite straightforward: all of those with even invariant are diffeomorphic to $\Sigma_0$ i.e. to $S^2 \times S^2$, while all of those with odd invariant are diffeomorphic to $\Sigma_1$. So in particular, by Kunnuth you get that $H^3$ is trivial and $H^2$ has rank $2$.

Comment: @TabesBridges : Thanks for your comment. They are not diffeomorphic, because if I remember correctly the intersection pairing is different.

Comment: @student : Thanks for the correction. By the way, I think Tabes is right, and something stronger even holds: $\Sigma_n$ is deformation equivalent to $\Sigma_{m}$ iff $n-m\equiv 0 \mod 2$. You see difference on intersection pairing because the diffeomorphism does not carry $\infty$-section to $\infty$-section, for example.

Comment: @TabesBridges : Sorry, my previous comment was wrong !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Topology of Hirzebruch Surface $\Sigma_2$**

Let $Z$ be the zero section and $E$ the $\infty$-section. Let $U=\Sigma_2-E$, $V=\Sigma_2-Z$ be the "neighborhoods" of zero and infinity section respectively, then the projection $U\to Z$ is the total space of line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(2)$, and $V\to E$ is the dual bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(-2)$. The two line bundles are glued together via $$z\mapsto z^{-1}$$
in fiber direction to get the compact manifold $\Sigma_2$ (See [my post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2746714)).
The intersection $U\cap V$ is diffeomorphic to $(0,\infty)\times (S^3/\mathbb Z_2)$, where the $\mathbb Z_2$ action on sphere $S^3$ is the antipodal map. Therefore $U\cap V$ has homotopy type $\mathbb R\mathbb P^3$.

By standard topology, $H_1(\mathbb R\mathbb P^3,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $H_2(\mathbb R\mathbb P^3,\mathbb Z)=0$. So In the Mayer-Vietoris sequence,

$$0\to H_3(X)\to 0\to \mathbb Z[Z]\oplus \mathbb Z[E]\xrightarrow{\sigma} H_2(X)\xrightarrow{\delta}\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to 0$$

By standard computation on intersection pairing, I claim that $H_2(X)\cong \mathbb Z[F]\oplus\mathbb Z[E]$, with $F$ being a fiber of $\Sigma_2\to Z$, and $\sigma([Z])=[E]+2[F]$. Also, tracing the connecting homomorphism in the level of chain complex, $[F]$ is the class whose image under $\delta$ is the generator of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. This answers the first two questions.

**Mixed Hodge Structure**

Actually, in this case $H^2(X)$ is still *pure*. To see this, the blowup $f:\Sigma_2\to X$ gives the exact sequence of *mixed hodge structures*
$$H^1(E)=0\to H^2(X)\xrightarrow{f^{*}}H^2(\Sigma_2)\to H^2(E)\to 0$$

by consider the relative cohomology of the pair $(X,E)$ and uses the fact that $\Sigma_2/E=X$ as CW complex. In particular, $H^2(X)$ includes in a pure Hodge structure, so it is automatically pure.

Comment: Thank you, your answer makes sense. I'll read it more carefully later !